# NHibernate, refresh modifed object throws AssertionFailure {null identifier}

Tags: c#, nhibernate, one-to-many

I use `NHibernate 4`,

I would like to implement a function which permit to refresh an modified object.
My object contains an ID and an association one-to-many with objects with ID2 ad a string

In my association, i insert a new object association, so `ID2` is null because it generate by `hilow` generator when save the main object in database.

so when i cause refresh for to reload the original object, I have an `assertion failure (null identifier)`  when there is an new object with `ID = null` (it's normally ok, no problem when i `saveOrUpdate`.
I put `notFound = ignore` in my mapping but with no effect when execute.

Please give me a way for resolve my problem

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question with some code, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> In my association, i insert a new object association, so ID2 is null because it generate by hilow generator when save the main object in database.

There is a somewhat inexact statement here. The `hilo` generator strategy generates the id before the object is inserted in database. It does it on `Save`, without `Save` actually inserting the entity into database until the session is flushed.

If your id stays `null`, this is very likely because you have not yet persisted the entity in the session. Call `Save` on it, and your id will no more be `null`, while the entity will not be yet in database unless you have flushed the session (or changed the generator strategy for one requiring immediate insert, as  `identity`).

Now refreshing an object not already in database looks anyway as an error to me. What do you expect from such an operation?

`not-found="ignore"` is not meant for handling refreshing of non existent entities. It is there for allowing ignoring an invalid foreign key in database.

Comment: ok, thank you for your help. I expect to reload my main object from database with the good timeqtamp because the flush indicate my object saved by another user since loading.

Comment: I don't wat to stop the application but refresh the objects.

Comment: I desappointed because I don't find a general code for this case : save with optimist transaction and timestamp is old.

Comment: i would like to reach a behavior  :  the user choose reload datas or crush the datas (reload the entire object or load the new timestamp for replace the old timestamp in the object.

Comment: Are you trying to reuse the session after the optimisitic failure? You should not. Open a new one, reload (not refresh, but `Load`) the object. Now you have the new one and the old one. Do what you want with them. (Including eventually `Merge`ing the old one in the new session.)

Comment: Thank you, I try to use your solution, I  think your solution is nice :-)

Comment: I post a comment Monday afternoon... Good Week end